# Why can't I get rid of this white space above my div?

Tags: css, html, whitespace

I can't figure out why there is about a 20 px white space above my div.  I'm trying to create a horizontal menu across the top of the page.  Here is the code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u6tA/) but the white space isn't showing up here.  Don't laugh at me but yes I'm still using Frontpage and it's not showing up there either.  It only shows up in browsers - Chrome, FF and IE9.

I've tried everything I can think of including making sure the margins are all set to 0:

```
html, body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

But nothing gets rid of that white space!

Comment: may be some other resources of your project are conflicting with this css...

Comment: Step 1. In Chrome, right-click and choose "Inspect Element" it will help you find the issue. Step 2. Set Frontpage on fire and start using a friendly text editor.

Comment: If it doesn't show up in your fiddle, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Have you tried loading a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) before your own styles? It could just be browser defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following to your style sheet:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

or add ul with your html, body declaration

```
html, body, ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Garry Cairns and Kim, both of those worked. I needed to set the ul margin to 0 as well.  Perfect!